# Timber\Image: Is it possible to flatten a transparent PNG onto a specific hex color?

Tags: wordpress, timber

I would like to convert a transparent PNG to JPG and specify a background color for the transparent areas, without having to specify a dimension.

Essentially, what I'm looking for is a combination of `Timber\Image`'s [tojpg](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/cookbook-images/#converting-images) and [letterbox](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/cookbook-images/#letterboxing-images) filters, minus `letterbox`'s width and height requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@hailseitan: try grabbing the current dimensions of the image via the `width()` and `height()` methods and then feeding them into `letterbox`!

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you!